# Crystal report - Header suppress

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal report how we suppress page header on pagenumber >= 2 when records are completed on the previous page

Comment: You should consider reframing the question. It is not possible to understand it when you merely going through a list.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Section Expert of the header.  Suppress it with the checkbox and then, in the suppression formula, do this (with Basic syntax):

if pagenumber > 1 then formula = true

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/MultiPageHeadersInCR07182006145156PM/MultiPageHeadersInCR.aspx) will help? Just make a couple headers and a conditional that hides on the non-first page...

Answer (score 0):

In the suppress formula box you can simply enter

```
Pagenumber<>1
```

This is true for all but the first page and thus will suppress on all but the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to suppress the header on the second page if there is no record in the Detail section.

Please take a look at

[Number of details records on the crystal report page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089400/number-of-details-records-on-the-crystal-report-page/8164928#8164928)