# Number of details records on the crystal report page

Tags: crystal-reports

i would like to find out the number of details records on the last page of the crystal report, and if there is none, I would like to hide the header section.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to create a formula.
Then, insert it into to the `Details` section.
For example `@VariableA`

Inside the formula, put this:

```
Shared NumberVar PageofLastField;
If OnLastRecord then PageofLastField := PageNumber;
```

Suppress formula.

The formula checks if the record is the last record.
If it is the last record, it saves the Page Number where the last record is to the shared  variable `PageofLastField`.
Then on the Suppress formula of your header, put this code:

```
Shared NumberVar PageofLastField;
PageofLastField := PageofLastField;
if pageofLastfield <> 0 and PageNumber > PageofLastField
    THEN TRUE
ELSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question correctly you should just be able to add a summary at the bottom of your page (maybe the Report Footer) to count an item in your details section. For instance I just opened up a report that I have and added a summary to count the number of zip codes in the details section.

[image]

The screen that you will see next allows you to select the Count for your summary.

[image]

Next I went to the Section Expert and put this in the X-2 box across from the Suppress check box in the Header Section.

[image]

If Count ({Stores.ZipCode}) > 50 Then True

This will suppress the header if I have more than 50 zip codes in my details section. In your case if your count is 0 then you would suppress. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: i will follow the steps and see how it goes. my purpose is to hide the header of the last page if there is no record on that page.

Comment: Now I understand what you are trying to do. I think PowerUser is correct though and this is going to be very tricky. Let me take another stab at it tomorrow and I will post a solution if I come up with something.

Comment: Sorry I got nothing. I have seen the question come up on other forums but I wasn't able to find anything that I could get to work the way you need.

Answer (score 0):

Suppressing the header based on a formula result is easy.  The hard part is counting the number of details sections that appear on a specific page.

AFAIK, that's just not possible without some tricky formatting.  For example, you could structure your report so that each page shows exactly 3 records at a time.  Then, if your total record count is 4 (which isn't divisible by 3), you know that your last page will contain exactly 1 record.

Answer (score -1):

Just using "OnLastRecord" in the Supress formula for PageHeader will solve the purpose.

Comment: This is just what Jerome's answer already said? How does your answer contribute?